# jqGrid plus sign stays after expanding SubGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In one case using jqGrid we have the situation that after expanding the subgrid the plus sign stays and a collapse fails. Every additional click on the plus sign will result in an additional subgrid.
The data in the subgrid is displayed correctly, but in some way jqGrid "thinks" the expansion "failed" as the plus icon is not replaced by the minus icon.

Anybody an idea what might be wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You should better post the demo which demonstrate the problem. Please use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` in the demo so that one could debug jqGrid code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that pager is set to true in the grid while it is set to false for the subgrid. As the subgrid has always one record we assigned assigned false. Selecting true is the workaround for this problem.

Hope this problem can be easily reproduced and fixed. (Note: for the grid we use the onSelectRow event in this case, which also is triggered clicking the expand (plus) icon. Not sure it is related to this bug. Just ignoring that event has no positive effect).